# nativescript-toast not showing on iOS

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

After I updated to the latest version of nativescript-toast it stopped working in iOS (In Android it's working fine). I mean, the toast are not being shown, while the app works as expected.

In the previous version everything was as expected. But after I update to the new one, it stop working and also added the pod SBToaster to my podfile.

This is the package.json

```
"nativescript-toast": "^2.0.0",
```

In the past I have the version 1.4.6

And in my Podfile I have:

```
pod 'SBToaster', '~> 2.1.2'
pod 'Toast'
```

In my component I have:

```
Toast.makeText(message).show();
```

Comment: May I know from which version you upgraded to which? Do you have a page-router-outlet (Frame) in your application?

Comment: Sure! I had the version 1.4.6. and yes, I have a page-router-outlet in the following way: '<page-router-outlet tkMainContent class="page page-content"></page-router-outlet>'

Comment: @Faabass Did you manage to fix that one?

Comment: No... not yet... are you having the same issue?

Comment: Which version of {NS} are you using?

Comment: @Narendra v 5.2.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was facing various compatibility issues with `nativescript-toast` plugin on latest SDK. The easiest way seem to be switching to [nativescript-toasty](https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-toasty) plugin which is more relevant and up to date.

```
tns plugin add nativescript-toasty
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58323839/angular-programmatically-close-alert-when-a-new-alert-is-triggered

Comment: @Manoj Is this possible?