# angular- programmatically close alert when a new alert is triggered

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-nativescript

I have two kinds of alerts- secondary alerts and delayed alerts
Secondary alert messgaes are shown at first and user has to hit OK button to close it.

But there are delayed alerts also..which are triggered by a `setTimeout()`
I'm trying to automatically close secondary alerts when this delayed alert is shown to user

I tried to dismiss the secondary alerts like this

```
this.secondaryAlertVar.dismiss();
```

But it's not working.

Here's the code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import * as dialogs from "tns-core-modules/ui/dialogs";
@Component({
    selector: "Home",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./home.component.html",
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    secondaryAlertVar: any;
    constructor() {
        this.secondaryAlerts(function () { }, 0, "Hhmm... ", "Alert");

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.delayedAlertBox("All other alerts should close automatically when this triggered");
        }, 10000);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    secondaryAlerts(callback, mode, message, title): any {
      this.secondaryAlertVar =  dialogs
            .alert({
                title: title,
                message: message,
                cancelable: false,
                okButtonText: "OK"
            })
            .then(callback);
    }

    delayedAlertBox(message) {
        this.secondaryAlertVar.dismiss();
        var options = {
            title: "Delayed Alert",
            message: message,
            okButtonText: "Ok",
            cancelable: false,
        };
        dialogs.alert(options).then(() => {
        });
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=dWQhV7&v=529&_ga=2.244207372.844477236.1570596665-623910499.1568785341)

Comment: You should probably use `rxjs` for this. If you did - you could possibly use `observable.pipe(takeUntil(delayedAlertBoxState$))` and play around that. :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't use nativescript but I presume this dialog box can produce a `promise` and you should be able to hook into that with [`from`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/from.html).

Comment: Take BehaviorSubject from rxjs, observe delayedAlerts. The secondary alert close event should subscribe to delayedAlerts observable. It will work but need to think and use it properly.

Comment: In your playground link you seems to be used some alert() on tap event. where does it declared

Comment: ` dialogs.alert(options).then(() => {
      this.secondaryAlertVar.dismiss();
        });`  will this work?

Comment: That alert() is of no use. Deleted it. @Abel

Comment: Tried that. It won't work. @Fan Cheung

Answer (score -1):

Try this using rxjs you can achieve this.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import * as dialogs from "tns-core-modules/ui/dialogs";
import { interval, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators'
@Component({
    selector: "Home",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./home.component.html",
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

      source = interval(0);
      alive = true;
      secondaryAlertVar: any;

      constructor() {

       const example = this.source.pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive));
       const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => {
        this.secondaryAlerts(function () { }, 0, "Hhmm... ", "Alert");
       });

        setTimeout(() => {
        this.alive = false;
            this.delayedAlertBox("All other alerts should close automatically when this triggered");
        }, 10000);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    secondaryAlerts(callback, mode, message, title): any {
      this.secondaryAlertVar =  dialogs
            .alert({
                title: title,
                message: message,
                cancelable: false,
                okButtonText: "OK"
            })
            .then(callback);
    }

    delayedAlertBox(message) {
        this.secondaryAlertVar.dismiss();
        var options = {
            title: "Delayed Alert",
            message: message,
            okButtonText: "Ok",
            cancelable: false,
        };
        dialogs.alert(options).then(() => {
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this code working? Some of your imports are unused.

Comment: I am updated my answer please check once. I hope it will help you.

Comment: use takeWhile instead of takeUntil. I have updated the answer please check once.

Comment: I tried this code with your latest changes. It's not working. Secondary alerts are not getting closed automatically when delayedAlert occurs.